# hide div tag on mobile view only?

Tags: css, fluid-layout

I'm creating a fluid layout for a site. I'm trying to hide the contents of a `<div>` or the whole `<div>` itself in the mobile view, but not the tablet and desktop view.

Here's what I've got so far...

```
#title_message {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px auto 5px 20px;
    width: 28%;
    display: none;
}
```

I have the display set to 'none' for the mobile layout and set as block on the tablet/desktop layouts... Is there an easier way to do that, or is that it?

Answer (score 204, accepted):

You will need two things.  The first is `@media screen` to activate the specific code at a certain screen size, used for responsive design.  The second is the use of the `visibility: hidden` attribute.  Once the browser/screen reaches 600pixels then `#title_message` will become hidden.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #title_message {
    visibility: hidden;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px auto 5px 20px;
    width: 28%;
    display: none;
  }
}
```

if you are using another CSS for mobile then just add the `visibility: hidden;` to `#title_message`.

Comment: When you come to StackOverflow... there's always going to be a solution to your query..... Except, most of the time I seem to come across slight alternatives.  ...This answer is exactly what I was looking for! ...Thank you Dude. (p.s. used for a custom mobile menu on my site http://amazewebs.com ...mobile menu will show when width<768px

Comment: It's working for me. Have to display only mobile pages@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
        .mobile-title {
            visibility: hidden;
        }
    }
    
    div.mobile-title h1 {
        text-align: center !important;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 5px;
    }

Answer (score 10):

The solution given didn't work for me on the desktop, it just showed both divs, although the mobile only showed the mobile div. So I did a little search and found the min-width option. I updated my code to the following and it works fine now :)

CSS:

```
    @media all and (min-width: 480px) {
    .deskContent {display:block;}
    .phoneContent {display:none;}
}

@media all and (max-width: 479px) {
    .deskContent {display:none;}
    .phoneContent {display:block;}
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="deskContent">Content for desktop</div>
<div class="phoneContent">Content for mobile</div>
```

Answer (score 9):

Set the display property to `none` as the default, then use a media query to apply the desired styles to the div when the browser reaches a certain width. Replace `768px` in the media query with whatever the minimum px value is where your div should be visible.

```
#title_message {
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    #title_message {
        clear: both;
        display: block;
        float: left;
        margin: 10px auto 5px 20px;
        width: 28%;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the wrong way round. The div won't display on browsers that don't support media queries.

Comment: respond.js https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond will solve this on older browsers that don't support media queries.  Media queries are the solution for responsive sites.

Comment: Of course they are the solution, but you're doing this **the wrong way round**. Unless your website is mostly used for mobile, you never build your css from the bottom up.

Comment: I don't consider mobile and desktop as separate websites. It is much easier to scale a project up as the browser gets bigger than it is to trim down as the browser gets smaller. In this case, KT is  building responsive site, regardless of if it is "mostly" used for mobile or simply optimized for all browsers. A mobile first approach saves the mobile browsers from having to load additional CSS styles that never are actually applied. This approach is not the _wrong way_, it's simply not the way you suggest building your css.

Comment: @MMM That's actually how mobile-first design is: from the bottom up.

Comment: @SepehrM look at my first comment and note that was 3 years ago when we still had to worry about browsers that don't support media queries

Comment: @MMM Oops, I thought it was 2015. Anyway I'm just against "you never build your css from the bottom up"

Answer (score 5):

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) { #title_message { display: none; }}
```

This would be for a responsive design with a single page for an iphone screen specifically. Are you actually routing to a different mobile page?

Comment: That didn't work. It wiped out all the CSS for the mobile layout.

Comment: Can you provide a small sample of your css then? I'm not seeing the whole picture here but that shouldn't have wiped out your layout

Comment: This work better, because visibility: hidden only hide the element but still there (the place remains). Instead display: none; really hide it and completely removing it.

Answer (score 3):

You can be guided by this example. On your css file:

```
.deskContent {
    background-image: url(../img/big-pic.png);
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain; 
}

.phoneContent {
    background-image: url(../img/small-pic.png);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}

@media all and (max-width: 959px) {
    .deskContent {display:block;}
    .phoneContent {display:none;}
}

@media all and (max-width: 479px) {
    .deskContent {display:none;}
    .phoneContent {display:block;}
}
```

On your html file:

```
<div class="deskContent">Content for desktop</div>
<div class="phoneContent">Content for mobile</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, I think that there are simple solutions than mentioned here on this page! first of all, let's make an example:

You have 1 DIV and want to hide thas DIV on Desktop and show on Mobile (or vice versa). So, let's presume that the DIV position placed in the `Head` section and named as `header_div`.

The global code in your `CSS file` will be: (for the same DIV):

```
.header_div {
    display: none;
}

@media all and (max-width: 768px){
.header_div {
    display: block;
}
}
```

So simple and no need to make 2 div's one for desktop and the other for mobile.

Hope this helps.

Thank you.

Comment: didn't work like this

Answer (score 1):

i just switched positions and worked for me (showing only mobile )

```html
<style>
 .MobileContent {

     display: none;
  text-align:center;

 }

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

 .MobileContent {

     display:block;

 }

}
</style>
<div class="MobileContent"> Something </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@media handheld{
    #title_message { display: none; }
}
```